# Nuxt Fatal Error starting nuxt in GitHub Actions

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, github-actions

I'm running a GitHub actions workflow that builds and runs a nuxt app for cypress.js testing. I'm receiving a Nuxt Fatal error that I can't seem to figure out from reading the stack when building the app.

FYI, I have looked through EVERY error logged in StackOverflow with this Fatal error but can't seem to find a solution.

Here's my GitHub Actions workflow (everything seems to run OK):

```
name: Cypress run on push

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        node: [14.17.0]
        containers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    steps:
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - run: node -v

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Running npm ci (installing dependencies)
        run: npm ci

      - name: Running npm install
        run: npm install
      
      # Update Browserlist
      - run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db

      - name: Starting test server and running Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm run start
          wait-on: 'http://localhost:3000/'
          wait-on-timeout: 120
          record: true
          parallel: true
          # browser: chrome
          # headless: true
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

And here is the error. I do not understand why there is an error referring to an unresolved path. The path is actually correct. This also runs locally, in a dev server, staging server, and production without any problem:

```
[fatal] Nuxt build error
  ERROR in ./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/svg/DottedNoteBook' in 'components/ui/dialogs'
  @ ./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 200:0-61 203:20-34
  @ ./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
  @ ./components/ui/dialogs/SocialMediaWrapper.vue
  @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/trial-view/_id.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
  @ ./pages/trial-view/_id.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
  @ ./pages/trial-view/_id.vue
  @ ./.nuxt/router.js
  @ ./.nuxt/index.js
  @ ./.nuxt/client.js
  @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

   ╭─────────────────────────────╮
   │                             │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
   │                             │
   │   Error: Nuxt build error   │
   │                             │
   ╰─────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! JurorSearch@2.18.6 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the JurorSearch@2.18.6 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-08-17T05_30_28_916Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: On the 3rd line of the error log you sent, it says that it can't resolve `@/components/svg/DottedNoteBook`.

If you've got a regular .svg file inside of your `/components` folder, I would move it to `/assets` and import it with `.svg` at the end of the path.

If it's a component, then try importing the component with `.vue` at the end of the path.

Comment: Thanks @Tarkan - "svg" is a directory and "DopttedNotebook" is a Vue component (actually "DottedNotebook.vue") that contains several functions for rendering svg's. It's not an svg file.

I'll try to add the .vue to the import, and see what happens. It is strange that this doesn't happen anywhere else except in the GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The component was calling "DottedNoteBook" but the file name is "DottedNotebook.vue". (Different case for the letter "B".)

I'm not sure why that case issue never came up before or preventing compiling outside of the GitHub Actions, but that was the issue. Thanks, @Tarkan for making me look closer at that.